# Пунктуация при словах "в порядке исключения"

Tags: пунктуация

Существует ли четкое определение в отношении конструкции "в порядке исключения"?
(Роль в предложении? Насколько постановка запятых зависит от места и роли в предложении?)
В частности:
**Предоставить в порядке исключения то или иное право...

Определить в порядке исключение того или иного участника...**

Все существующие и мне известные источники пересмотрены. Прихожу к выводу, что, как правило, обособление не нужно, т.к. конструкция включает в себя ключевой момент и несет не последнюю,  а зачастую — самую главную нагрузку в предложении.
P.S. Больше, конечно, интересует официально-деловой стиль, потому как в художественной литературе допустима авторская пунктуация.

Answer (score 1):

*Сделать что-то в порядке исключения.* Здесь "в порядке исключения" — обстоятельство образа действия. Такие обстоятельства, как правило, не обособляются, однако можно допустить, что в определенном контексте слова "в порядке исключения" служат присоединительной конструкцией (выступают как  дополнительное разъяснение или замечание), особенно если можно добавить слово "причем".

Почувствуйте разницу:

Предоставить в порядке исключения то или иное право.
Предоставить, (причем) в порядке исключения, то или иное право.

Не думаю, что в официальном письме кто-то станет обособлять "в порядке исключения".